# Why does the grammar for function definitions in the Python3 documentation seem to require the '/' token in parameter_list?

Tags: python, function-declaration, ebnf

The relevant [section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) from the Python3 documentation:

```
funcdef                   ::=  [decorators] "def" funcname "(" [parameter_list] ")"
                               ["->" expression] ":" suite
decorators                ::=  decorator+
decorator                 ::=  "@" assignment_expression NEWLINE
dotted_name               ::=  identifier ("." identifier)*
parameter_list            ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* "," "/" ["," [parameter_list_no_posonly]]
                                 | parameter_list_no_posonly
parameter_list_no_posonly ::=  defparameter ("," defparameter)* ["," [parameter_list_starargs]]
                               | parameter_list_starargs
parameter_list_starargs   ::=  "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," ["**" parameter [","]]]
                               | "**" parameter [","]
parameter                 ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter              ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
funcname                  ::=  identifier
```

My understanding of EBNF is that the above grammar for `parameter_list` requires the "," and "/" characters, since they appear alone and aren't wrapped in `[]` or followed by a `*`. Obviously they *aren't actually* required, and Python is perfectly happy to accept basic function definitions like `def say_hello(input_name)`, so is this a mistake in the documentation, or have I misunderstood how to read the grammar?

Answer (score 2):

`parameter_list` has `| parameter_list_no_posonly`, so can just be `parameter_list_no_posonly`, which doesn't have `"," "/"`.

Comment: Ah, so the `|` extends to the entire expression, not just to the adjacent term? As in: `<token> ::= X Y | Z` is equivalent to `<token> ::= (X Y) | Z`, rather than `<token> ::= X (Y | Z)`.

Comment: @MontyEvans Yes.